# reference form in angular component without scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-components

Currently I have this component definition:

```
    var controller = ['$http', '$timeout', '$scope', function($http, $timeout, $scope) {
        this.isInvalid = function() {
            return $scope.changePinForm.$invalid;
        };      
    }];

    var component = {
        templateUrl: path.fromRoot('/application/libs/components/pin-change/view/pin-change.html'),
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };

    angular.module('pin-change', ['confirm-reject', 'compare-validator', 'is-numeric'])
        .component('pinChange', component);
});
```

Which references this html file via `templateUrl`:

```
<form name="changePinForm" class="form-horizontal">
  <!-- etc. etc. -->
</form>
```

At the moment I am having to use scope to reference the form:

```
$scope.changePinForm.$invalid;
```

I would prefer to avoid scope and reference the form from the component's controller.

Is this possible or is scope still the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make your form name to be `name="vm.changePinForm"` use `vm`(controller alias).

And then you can easily access `vm.changePinForm.$invalid` inside your controller. By which you aren't depending on `$scope` inside your controller.

```
var controller = ['$http', '$timeout', 
  function($http, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.isInvalid = function() {
        return vm.changePinForm.$invalid;
    };      
  }
];
```